Microcontroller - Difficulty with CMCON and MCLR commands
I'm having difficulty understanding how two command lines work, one that is described and the other in the microcontroller hardware section where we have the following condition:
TRISA = 0x00; //All RA pins are outputs
TRISB = 0x00; //All RB pins are outputs
CMCON = 0x07; //disable comparators

  while(1) { //Loop infinite
    PORTA.RA0 = 1; //LED ON
    Delay_ms(1000); //1 Second de Delay
    PORTA.RA0 = 0; //LED OFF
    Delay_ms(1000); //1 Second de Delay
  }

This programming makes the LED blink every second, but I would like to know what this CMCON command means. According to the gpt chat:
CMCON is the control register for the analog comparators of the PIC16F628A.
The microcontroller has comparators that share pins with the PORTA. To use these pins as digital inputs/outputs, the comparators need to be disabled.
Even so, I don't understand.
I know that if I set the PORT(s) to zero, they will all be outputs, so should this command line exist? Because I am setting it for all outputs.
I simulated another situation and it worked normally, but I made a plus, I put a resistor and a switch in the clear. Even without doing the Clear command (code), it works. In this case, can I do this in real life with the microcontroller without having to program the Clear?


You are using RA0 which is the input of a comparator, not the output. So, I guess you do not have to disable the comparator. You only need to disable the comparator if you would like to use RA3 and RA4 as digital input or digital output .

You are strongly recommended to read the manufacturers' datasheets and avoid very frequently unreliable secondary sources such as blogs and tutorials and most especially unverifiable "AI" output.
As background, you have to know that in very many microcontrollers, there are more "peripherals" (GPIO, timers, comparators, serial interfaces, etc) than you can fit on the number of pins.  And so the manufacturers put several of them on the same pins, with some method to switch between them.  Sometimes it's difficult to understand the other uses of pins you want to do something simple with.  That's what is going on here.
The datasheet for the PIC16F628A is available from the Microchip website
The first question is what does CMCON do; the second question is what is its value after reset?

Section 5.1: The PIC16F627A/628A/648A have two ports, PORTA
and PORTB. Some pins for these I/O ports are
multiplexed with alternate functions for the peripheral
features on the device. In general, when a peripheral is
enabled, that pin may not be used as a general
purpose I/O pin.
[...]
The PORTA pins are multiplexed with comparator and
voltage reference functions. The operation of these
pins are selected by control bits in the CMCON
(Comparator Control register)

It continues by showing the many options.  What you have in your code is a standard "just do IO" setup: make all the port pins outputs and disable the comparators.
In this particular instance (using PA0) you could get away with not disabling the comparators because you're only using one output pin which happens to be a comparator input.  But your code says "make all pins outputs" which makes it look like you will/might/plan to use them all.  If the comment says one thing and the code does another, you should consider it a bug.
Additionally, if the comparators are enabled, if you read back from PORTA, you will get zeros for the comparator bits; you may very well expect to see what you last wrote.  If you use a read-modify-write instruction, this can be very surprising and confusing.
We see in the diagram that a 1 in the CMCON bit will force a zero in the read-back value.  (It's the AND gate in the diagram, labelled input buffer.)

The datasheet shows CMCON <= 7 as the standard way to initialise PORTA.  (Example 5.1).  Table 10-1 shows that setting it to 7 disables the comparators and makes the inputs digital; also shows that 0 is the power-on-reset state, with the inputs being analogue.

[table continues]
PS. There is also VRCON, and this is reset to a disabled state, and so you don't need to be concerned with it until you want to use it.

The TRIS overrides the analog input, so you can still use the pin as an output regardless of whether the comparator is enabled or not.
However, by my reading, RA0 always reads as '0' when the pin is enabled as analog, so you could have inadvertent clearing of RA0 if you perform a RMW (read-modify-write) instruction that is intended to affect a different bit in PORT A.
The PIC16F628 is a really old part- newer ones have LAT registers which avoid the RMW issue.

Ah, the joys of multi-use I/O pins! Data sheet suggests that doing a READ of PORTA could cause RA0 to be low, if power-on register setup is not modified [comparators are active by default]. But reading TRISA is similar to reading LATCHA on a more modern part. To be safe, comparator should be disabled by writing 0x07 to CMCON soon after power-up.
